# c# group by multiple columns then select all fields where count > 1

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a lambda query like this,

```
        List<string> ticketStatusOrder = new List<string>() { "Attended", "Issued", "Unpaid", "Cancelled" };

        var duplicate = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(x => ticketStatusOrder.IndexOf(x["TicketStatus"].ToString()))
            .GroupBy(x => new {EventID = x["EventID"].ToString(), ContactID = x["ContactID"].ToString()})
            .Select(x =>
            {
                var first = x.First();
                //return new {first.ItemArray};
                return new
                {
                    Type = first["type"],
                    Name = first["name"],
                    EventID = first["EventID"],
                    ContactID = first["ContactID"],
                    TicketStatus = first["TicketStatus"]
                };
            }).ToDataTable();
```

Its not returning the correct order by number, anyhelp? thanks

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => new { x["ReferenceID"], x["EventID"] }).Where(z => a.Count() > 1)`

Comment: that doesnt get the group the other value of debtor type and lagacy type and its in a group i dont want to be in a group of fields.i want it to be outside of it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution by doing

```
  var duplicate = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => new {EventID = x["EventID"].ToString(), ContactID = x["ContactID"].ToString()})
            .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
            .Select(x =>
            {
                var first = x.First();
                return new
                {
                    Type = first["type"],
                    Name = first["name"],
                    EventID = first["EventID"],
                    ContactID = first["ContactID"]
                };
            }).ToDataTable()
```

Another question,can we return new first.ItemArray something like that to return whatever is in first? thanks